# Best projects that illustrate the strengths of the languages they are implemented in?

Tags: programming-languages, open-source

I'm looking for a who's who list of projects(open source) that really illustrate the strength of the languages they are written in.  Ideally the project should make use of some features of a given language that would otherwise be clunky or difficult to do in another language.

Comment: Please read What "kind of questions should I not ask here?" http://programmers.stackexchange.com/faq

Answer (score 6):

Ruby on Rails makes astoundingly good use of Ruby's pervasive dynamicness. I'm not a Ruby-head really, but I've done a substantial amount of Rails programming, and what it does with the language is mind-boggling at times.

Comment: Dynamic generation of finders is a very good example of this.  The actual methods that find models in rails are dynamically generated the first time they're called.  When the model gets a call to a method that doesn't exist, it parses the name of the call and generates a method to search the database.  Rails "Magic" is awesome!

Answer (score 2):

[Boost::Spirit::Qi](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_0/libs/spirit/doc/html/spirit/qi/tutorials/warming_up.html) really shows off operator overloading and template metaprogramming in C++. The library can be annoying to use at times because it doesn't always give the best of error messages, but if you need to recognize a little language quickly it lets you build recursive decent parsers using EBNF style syntax without leaving C++ or using an external code generator.

Answer (score 0):

The following modules are either already in the D standard library or candidates for inclusion and really highlight the strength of D template metaprogramming:

- [std.algorithm](http://digitalmars.com/d/2.0/phobos/std_algorithm.html)
- [std.range](http://digitalmars.com/d/2.0/phobos/std_range.html)
- [std.parallelism](http://cis.jhu.edu/~dsimcha/d/phobos/std_parallelism.html)